# Monero fork wont mine blocks after height 3062

Tags: daemon, monero-forks, block-height

I have forked Monero and created the genesis block. Everything seems to be working fine till the block height reaches `3062` and then there are no blocks mined after that. Currently, my blockchain is running Monero v7. The current difficulty is `31946276` and the network hash rate is `266.218 kH/s`. Its been 5 hours the height has been at `3062`.

I am getting the below warning in my daemon, I am not sure if the issue is related.

```
2019-02-02 07:49:34.903 [P2P6]  WARN    global  src/p2p/net_node.inl:1332       No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 17070
```

I have also set the default p2p port to `17070` in the config.

Can anyone help me fix this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now that block is creating after height 3062 but the block creation time is very high, it took almost 20 minutes to mine a block. Is this a common scenario in monero v7

Comment: Normal behavior: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10853/7493

Answer (score 1):

Block creation sometimes takes more time and sometimes less, also the time to be mined increases with difficulty.

Your daemon functions properly without any incoming connections, but if you want to open port `17070` in the right way, you have to forward/open it in your router too and not only in Linux/Windows firewall.