# Monero fork: block creation time fluctuation

Tags: mining, blockchain, monero-forks

I am running a Monero fork(v7) for the past 4 days. I have set the block creation time as 2 minutes but sometimes the blockchain takes more than 30 minutes to create a block. Is this normal behavior?

Below are my network details

```
Difficulty: 79447867
Network Hash: 662.065 kH/s
Hard Fork: v7
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is normal. Block creation is random. Sometimes it'll take more time than your target, and sometimes less.

Think of it as flipping a coin. You can expect tails in... hmm... a bit more than 1.5 tries I think. But if you try it, sometimes you'll get tails in just one try, and sometimes it'll take 20 tries. But the average will converge to about the expected if you try for long enough.

<s>By the way: I see you are forking with the existing Monero chain. If you do not start your own chain, you are a bad person. See [How can individuals safeguard themselves and the community against a key reusing fork?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/how-can-individuals-safeguard-themselves-and-the-community-against-a-key-reusing/7844?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.4953#7844) for details.</s> I misread the hash rate, this looks like a new chain, all good :)

Comment: I am not forking with existing Monero chain. My blockchain running on a different network.

Comment: Different network does not equal different chain. To create a different chain, start it from a new genesis block. Do not share any history.

Comment: My apologies, I had read MH instead of kH, it looked like the Monero chain :) This is fine then, I'll strike that comment in the post.

Comment: Now it is taking more than 2-3 hours to create a block sometimes, this happens twice daily. During this period the network difficulty remains the same. Also I have noticed that the pool hash rate is 1.5 MH/s but the network hash rate is only 743 KH/s. Why the total pool hash rate is not reflected in the network hash rate?

Comment: Is this because there is no enough miners in the network, currently we have only 5 miners

Comment: It's about the total hash rate, not the number of miners. At 1.5 MH/s, you should be mostly fine. 2-3 hours to create block twice daily seems too much for normal variation. Are you sure some of your miners don't disconnect at those times ?

Comment: All the miners where connected on those times. Also I didn't understand why the total pool hash rate is not reflected in the network hash rate. The network hash rate is only 2.5 MH/s but the total pool hash rate is 6.2 MH/s

Comment: Difficulty depends on the last... 720 blocks or so. So it can take a bit of time for it to zero in on the actual hash rate.